# Playing a song again using a "Stop Play" then a "Play Sound" button in Android Media Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have setup an Android Media Player, which works each time I start (or restart) the app, in that it plays music whenever I push "Play Music".

However, should I push "Stop Music", then "Play Music", no music plays, and I have to restart my app. Obviously, this is less than ideal. I have tried using the .prepare() methods, (which I found out about by searching SO in the first place for an answer to this query), but they don't seem to be working for me. What do I need to do so that the buttons work all the time, not just once a session? Below is the source code for both the "Play Music" and "Stop Music" buttons. Any help would be gratefully received.

The MediaPlayer code I've written is here:

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.insomnimix);

```
public void stopSoundButtonListener() {
 Button stopSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopSoundButton);
 //When this method is called, stop the current sound playing.
 stopSound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override

     public void onClick(View arg0) {
         if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true)  {
             Context context = getApplicationContext();
             CharSequence text = "Stopping Music";
             int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
             toast.show();

             mediaPlayer.stop();

         } else {
             Context context = getApplicationContext();
             CharSequence text = "The music is already stopped.";
             int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
             toast.show(); 
         }

        }



 });
 }
```

Now here is the "Play Music" button code:

```
 public void playSoundButtonListener() {
 Button playSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playSoundButton);
 //When this method is called, start the sound playing.
 playSound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override

     public void onClick(View arg0) {

         if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
             try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             mediaPlayer.start();

         }


     }});
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pause() instead of stop()?

Comment: No, not yet. What I'd like to do is to allow users to both pause and stop (and thus restart) music as they please. Tomorrow, I'll probably add the pause() functionality, though that's not really what I'm after in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hello, yes, your suggestion did in fact work. Many thanks!

Comment: Indeed this works for MediaPlayer but not for AACPlayer that only have Stop method. This redirect to my similar issue but with AACPlayer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220026/android-aacplayer-play-then-stop-then-play-again/24031178#24031178